# JodaTime Calculate total hours worked in a week

Tags: java, jodatime

Currently I have a function which can take the start time and end time of one day, and calculate the difference between the two, giving me the hours worked in a day. What I would like to do is be able to get the hours worked for 7 days, and return a grand total, while remaining with the display format (HH:mm).

My function for a single day's total:

```
Period p = new Period(this.startTime[dayIndex], this.endTime[dayIndex]);
long hours = p.getHours();
long minutes = p.getMinutes();

String format = String.format("%%0%dd", 2);//Ensures that the minutes will always display as two digits.

return Long.toString(hours)+":"+String.format(format, minutes);
```

this.startTime[] & this.endTime[] are both arrays of DateTime objects.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution I ended with for those interested

```
    Period[] p=new Period[7];
    long hours = 0;
    long minutes =0;
    for(int x=0; x<=this.daysEntered;x++)
    {
        p[x] = new Period(this.startTime[x], this.endTime[x]);
        hours += p[x].getHours();
        minutes += p[x].getMinutes();
    }

    hours += minutes/60;
    minutes=minutes%60;

    String format = String.format("%%0%dd", 2);

    return Long.toString(hours)+":"+String.format(format, minutes);
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need something to hold a week's worth of days, and call your function once for each day.

But that means you'll want to refactor so that your calculator method doesn't format as a string, but instead returns a numeric value, so you can easily add them together.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple solution:

Here is a method that receives separate the hours and minutes.
The parameters are:

- Start Hour
- Start Minutes
- End Hour
- End Minutes

first, calculate the difference between hours and minutes separate:

```
int hours   = pEndHour - pStartHour;
int minutes = ((60 - pStartMinutes) + pEndMinutes) - 60;
```

then, validates if the value of "minutes" variable is negative:

```
// If so, the "negative" value of minutes is our remnant to the next hour
 if (minutes < 0) {
  hours--;
  minutes = 60 + minutes ;
 }
```

Finally you can print the period of time in the hour format:

```
String format = String.format("%%0%dd", 2);
System.out.println( "*** " + hours + " : " + minutes);
```

That's all.